# Core Data/SQLite Store Occasional Data Loss

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

This problem is infrequent and intermittent but extremely troubling.

I have an app that uses CoreData with sqlite persistent store, and which [most of the time] works perfectly. However, I'm getting occasional reports of data loss that I cannot find.

When a Core Data item is changed, we persist it with a call to the following:

```
- (void) saveContext
{
    if ([context hasChanges])
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to save context: %@", error);
            [self displayValidationError:error];
        }
    }
}
```

My question centers around whether, given the saving of the content, once this method has been called, is final, or is some of it possibly cached and subject to loss.

We are not sure but this problem seems to occur when the app is backgrounded after a series of items has been entered.  If the app is forcibly terminated by the user, we can definitely cause data loss. It seems this occurs when the user leaves the app untouched for a little while and perhaps uses the device for something else.

I call saveContext from the AppDelegate (applicationwillTerminate and applicationWillResignActive).

So, my questions:

- Are the calls from AppDelegate adequate to ensure persistence?
- When the call to saveContext (shown above) is made, is there something else required to guarantee that all unsaved entities are flushed to disk?
- Am I overlooking something that could be causing this?

TIA for any assistance on the subject.  I've been able to find very little that seems similar to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are the calls from AppDelegate adequate to ensure persistence?

There's no guarantee that `applicationWillTerminate` will be called. If your app has unsaved data and iOS terminates the app (because it's been in the background for a while), you can't rely on that method.

> When the call to saveContext (shown above) is made, is there something else required to guarantee that all unsaved entities are flushed to disk?

There's no "flush changes to the persistent store" call. Saving is it, but you need to save at appropriate times.

You should really save changes **any time you have data you don't want to lose**. Relying on system events means that you're leaving unsaved changes, well, unsaved for potentially long periods. If you have changes you want to persist, save them as soon as they are made.